# D3js week calendar

Tags: d3.js

I need for a study project to represent event occurrences on a week calendar like the one below:
[image]

each pink line represents the day and time the event occurred.
my issue is that although I know how to setup the axes, I don't know how to make the event display a small line and not a dot

can anyone please give me a hint on this ? thanks a lot in advance !!!

Michael

Comment: Isn't this a better option http://fullcalendar.io/ than going d3

Comment: @Cyril : events have no duration and it is solely for representation purpose. a "kind of heat map" without categories.

Comment: Are you required to use D3? This is a very odd use for it... sure it can be done but good 'ol html, css, js could do it much easier.